# Orchard.Utility does not exist

Tags: orchardcms

I have been given an ASP.NET website to host on a server, it is using orchard and almost everything compiles, however on file references `Orchard.Utility.Extensions`. Visual studio is suggesting that this namespace is non-existent, bearing in mind that all other references to namespaces contained in `Orchard` are resolving.

I believe that I have the most up to date Orchard version, am I missing something?

Comment: Orchard uses dynamic compilation, so it will probably be resolved when you start the website. If you want to get rid of the error message in VS you can of course just add a project reference to `Orchard.Framework`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try starting the website and get back to you on it

Comment: @devqon failed to compile with 14000 errors, I think I've got bigger things on my hands than just the reference now :P

Comment: First try to build Orchard.Framework Project then Orchard.Core and Orchard.Web

Comment: What is the exact error message?